# Display content by using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am Building `comments` feature in my application by using `Angularjs`. So I have a problem in displaying the `data`. I am getting data from server like this:

```
    This is the core collection of directives you would use in your template 
code to build an AngularJS application.\n\nSome examples include: ngClick, ngInclude
```

the data contains `\n`. it indicates `new Line`.For displaying that data I am using `ng-bind-html` directive with `$sce.trustAsHtml(data);`. But data is displaying in same line not added new lines.

Can any one Help me Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default whitespace is collapsed within HTML.  To get around that, you should use a `<pre>` tag.  White space will no be collapsed within a `pre` tag.

#### with `<p>`

```
<p>
lots of text 
with new lines 
look like this
</p>
```

lots of text 
with new lines 
look like this

#### with `<pre>`

```
<pre>
lots of text 
with new lines 
look like this
</pre>
```

```
lots of text 
with new lines 
look like this
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<pre>` which assumes you want to format the entire string, you can simply replace `"\n"` with `<br>`:

```
data.replace("\n","<br>");
```